# Add Microsoft.office.interop.Access.Dao to GAC

Tags: c#, gac

I am facing an issue while adding Microsoft.office.interop.Access.Dao to my project. Getting the reference not found as given below.

[image]

My intnsion is to add the DLL to GAC so that it will list as below

[image]

But when i tried to register the dll using Regsvr32 i am getting the below error [image]

Comment: regsvr32 is for COM libraries. Use [GacUtil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/gacutil-exe-gac-tool) to add .NET assemblies to the GAC.

Comment: I would also note that you shouldn't need to do this manually. They should be installed automatically when you install either Office or the Tools for Office runtime distributable, One of those is necessary to create office add-ins. If you don;t have one of those installed then the app will fail at runtime.

Comment: Able to add the dll using gacutil. But still in the Visual studio solution it is showing as not found